# Terraform combine multiple attribute blocks into one

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I am trying to automate and provision DataBricks cluster in DataBricks workspace using terraform.

We have predefined libraries which need to be installed on cluster creation, we do have roughly 20 libraries

```
variable"libraries"{
default = ["pypi","jar"]
}

variable"pythonpackages"{
default = ["conda","pymongo"]
}

variable"jarpackages"{
default = ["etc1","etc1"]
}

variable"repositories"{
default = ["internal1","internal2"]
}

resource "databricks_cluster" "shared_autoscaling" {

  cluster_name            = "Shared Autoscaling"
  spark_version           = data.databricks_spark_version.latest_lts.id
  node_type_id            = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
  autotermination_minutes = 20
  autoscale {
    min_workers = 1
    max_workers = 50
  }
  library { 
    pypi  {
        package = "dnspython"
        }
    }
      library { 
    pypi  {
        package = "condo"
        }
    }
         library { 
    pypi  {
        package = "kedro"
        repo = "artifactory-url"
        }
    }
  
}
```

I am trying to remove the library attribute duplicacy. I tried it with `for_each` inside the library attribute but it did not work out right.

What I am trying to achieve

```
variable"libraries"{
default = ["pypi","jar"]
}

variable"pythonpackages"{
default = ["conda","pymongo"]
}

variable"jarpackages"{
default = ["etc1","etc1"]
}

variable"repositories"{
default = ["internal1","internal2"]
}

resource "databricks_cluster" "shared_autoscaling" {

  cluster_name            = "Shared Autoscaling"
  spark_version           = data.databricks_spark_version.latest_lts.id
  node_type_id            = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
  autotermination_minutes = 20
  autoscale {
    min_workers = 1
    max_workers = 50
  }

      library { 
    pypi  {
        package = ["condo","pymongo","listofpackages"]
        }
    }
  
}
```

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, but dynamic blocks is what you're looking for: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) to repeat nested blocks.

To repeat the library block for example, you can write:

```
resource "databricks_cluster" "shared_autoscaling" {
  cluster_name            = "Shared Autoscaling"
  spark_version           = data.databricks_spark_version.latest_lts.id
  node_type_id            = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
  autotermination_minutes = 20
  autoscale {
    min_workers = 1
    max_workers = 50
  }
  
  dynamic "library" {
    for_each = ["condo","pymongo","listofpackages"]
    content {
      pypi {
        package = library.value
      }
    }
  }
 }
```